# SQL Replacing NULL with 0 in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace a Null value with a 0 and then do a calculation on this field, but not able to make it work.  In all 4 of the examples below I'm still getting a Null value.

Any suggestions with how to write this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
select
ISNULL(posamt, 0)   as total1,
    coalesce (posamt, 0) as total2,     
    case when PosAmt = 0 then '0' else CONVERT(varchar(11), isnull(posamt, 0))end as total3,
    CONVERT(varchar(11),isnull(posamt,0)) as total4
from mytable
```

[image]

Comment: What table are you using?  Where's the rest of your query?

Comment: These should work.  My guess is that the value is `'NULL'` the string and not `NULL` the value.

Comment: Posted the rest of my query.

Comment: The results that you show are not for the query that is run -- the first column is different.

Comment: I can't share the whole query for privacy of the client, so I had to shorten the select statement in my post above.

Comment: What is the data type for posamt? Could you run the same query showing the actual value of posamt?

Comment: are you not allowed to update it first?

Comment: why query and result in screenshot don't match?

Comment: Don't share the whole query. Remove all irrelevant columns and show us the actual query that you run and actual result that you get. Most likely as you do it, you'll figure out yourself where the problem is. `ISNULL(posamt, 0)` will never return `NULL`. There must be something else, like `LEFT JOIN` or `UNION`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - that's it.  I did have a left join which was causing the problem.  Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have the ISNULL(posamt,0) in the CASE WHEN statements.   It will never be equal to 0 when posamt is NULL.